# Craft Pro Adding Users no email is sent

Tags: users

I am adding new users in Craft Pro, I don't get a chance to specify password, seems its is auto generated but I don't get any email sent to the user I just created. Is there any setting I have missed?

I have setup Gmail in settings >> Email >> Protocol and tested and received test email but doesn't send email when a new user is added.

Any help will be appreciated.﻿

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't get a chance to specify password, seems its is auto generated but I don't get any email sent to the user I just created.

From the CP, you can't create a password for a user.  They'll receive an email, in which they can click on an activation link and they can set their own password by following the workflow.

There is extra logic in registering a new user from the CP that will detect if Craft can create the user, but not send the email, and the CP will notify you if that is the case.

It sounds like maybe the email is being sent, but caught up in a SPAM filter somewhere.

You can also check through your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files to see if any [error] or [warning] entries are getting logged.

Comment: Hi Brad,I have checked log(craft.log and phperrors.log) but no error or warning regarding user is been logged. This is a strange one

Comment: Do you have any SMTP credentials you could try?  (or any other email protocol)

Comment: Still no luck, tried SMTP, PMPMail. I will upload online and see if it makes any difference as right now am working on localhost.Thanks for taking time to look at this Brad.

Comment: Fair enough. Be sure and update here if you find a solution!

Comment: Hi Brad I have this site online now...still not sending email.

Comment: Another alternative is to use a service like Mandrill or  MailCatcher. The former will help your chances of guaranteeing the mail will get delivered, and both will have a log of mails sent - which will allow you to at least exclude Craft from the equation. Email is tricky.

Comment: @FredCarlsen Good call... we actually use Mandrill for buildwithcraft.com and are happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with some german email providers (web.de, gmx). PHP-Mail and Sendmail failed but the solution for me was to use a smtp server in the email configs of Craft.